# numpy/pandas vectorize custom for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I created some example code that mimic what code I got:

```
import numpy as np 

arr = np.random.random(100)
arr2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
arr3 = np.zeros(20) # this is the array i want to store the result in
for index, num in enumerate(list(arr2)):
    arr3[index] = np.mean(arr[np.abs(num - arr) < 0.2])

>>> arr3
array([0.10970893, 0.1132479 , 0.14687451, 0.17257954, 0.19401919,
       0.23852137, 0.29151448, 0.35715096, 0.43273118, 0.45800796,
       0.52940421, 0.60345354, 0.63969432, 0.67656363, 0.72921913,
       0.78330793, 0.82693675, 0.83717402, 0.86651827, 0.89782569])
```

My problem is this code runs on much larger data. I want to know if it is possible to make some combination of numpy or pandas to do it in a vectorized way without using explicit loops. I tried many approaches but don't have something in my mind.

Comment: Look at `arr2[:,None]-arr`.  That should be a (20,100) array.  `np.mean` takes an `axis` parameter letting you reduce that to a (20,) result.

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand... can you demonstrate it?

Comment: I'd recommend `np.empty_like` rather than `np.zeros` for `arr3`

Comment: No need to turn `arr2` into a list to enumerate it. It will iterate just fine as an array

Comment: @hpaulj. The difference you show builds a mask. How do you propose applying it to compute the mean? Masked arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend a completely different approach if you are dealing with large arrays. Right now, you are searching through the entirety of `arr` for every element in `arr2`. This is clearly overkill. Instead, you can operate on a sorted `arr` and simply sum between the insertion points obtained from [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html).

Sort `arr` in place if you can:

```
arr.sort()
```

You know the width of your interval, so find the bounding values. I'm making the array shaped `(20, 2)` to match the bounds more easily:

```
bounds = arr2.reshape(-1, 1) + [-0.2, 0.2]
```

Now find the insertion indices:

```
ind = np.searchsorted(arr, bounds)
```

`ind` is the same shape as `bounds`. `ind[i, :]` are the start (inclusive) and end (exclusive) indices into `arr` that correspond to the `i`th element of `arr2`. In other words, for any given `i`, `arr3[i]` in the original question is `arr[ind[i, 0]:ind[i, 1]].mean()`. You can use this directly for a non-vectorized solution:

```
result = np.array([arr[slice(*i)].mean() for i in ind])
```

There are a couple of ways to vectorize the solution. In either case, you'll want the number of elements in each run:

```
n = np.diff(ind, axis=1).ravel()
```

A quick and dirty solution that is prone to rounding errors uses [`np.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and fancy indexing using `ind`:

```
cumulative = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(arr)]
sums = np.diff(cumulative[ind], axis=1).ravel()
result = sums / n
```

A more robust solution would extract only the sums that you actually need using [`np.add.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html):

```
arr = np.r_[arr, 0]  # compensate for index past the end
sums = np.add.reduceat(arr, ind.ravel())[::2]
result = sums / n
```

You can compare the results of both approaches to `arr3` computed in the question to verify that the second approach is noticeably more accurate, even with your toy example.

**Timing**

```
def original(arr, arr2, d):
    arr3 = np.empty_like(arr2)
    for index, num in enumerate(arr2):
        arr3[index] = np.mean(arr[np.abs(num - arr) < d])
    return arr3

def ananda(arr, arr2, d):
    arr_tile = np.tile(arr, (len(arr2), 1))
    arr_tile[np.abs(arr - arr2[:, None]) >= d] = np.nan
    return np.nanmean(arr_tile, axis=1)

def mad_0(arr, arr2, d):
    arr.sort()
    ind = np.searchsorted(arr, arr2.reshape(-1, 1) + [-d, d])
    return np.array([arr[slice(*i)].mean() for i in ind])

def mad_1(arr, arr2, d):
    arr.sort()
    ind = np.searchsorted(arr, arr2.reshape(-1, 1) + [-d, d])
    n = np.diff(ind, axis=1).ravel()
    sums = np.diff(np.r_[0, np.cumsum(arr)][ind], axis=1).ravel()
    return sums / n

def mad_2(arr, arr2, d):
    arr.sort()
    ind = np.searchsorted(arr, arr2.reshape(-1, 1) + [-d, d])
    n = np.diff(ind, axis=1).ravel()
    arr = np.r_[arr, 0]
    sums = np.add.reduceat(arr, ind.ravel())[::2]
    return sums / n
```

Inputs (reset for each run):

```
np.random.seed(42)
arr = np.random.rand(100)
arr2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
```

Results:

```
original: 25.5 ms ± 278 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
  ananda: 2.66 ms ± 35.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
   mad_0: 14.5 ms ± 48.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
   mad_1:  211 µs ± 1.41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
   mad_2:  242 µs ± 1.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For 100 elements with 1k bins, the original approach is ~10x slower than using `np.tile`. Using a list comprehension is only 2x better than the original approach. While the `np.cumsum` approach appears to be a little faster than `np.add.reduce`, it is potentially not as numerically stable.

Another advantage of using the methods I suggest is that you can change `arr2` arbitrarily, while `arr` only needs to be sorted once.

Comment: there is an error, tough it seems right, but i cant figure out the error because i stiull didnt fully understand the whole process... error:in line  `sums = np.diff(cumulative[ind], axis=1)`  error: `IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100`

Comment: im testing it and trying to figure out if you have an idea i will be  waiting here :) thank you very much!

Comment: @adirabargil. I'll work out the bugs when I get to a desktop. In the meantime, to help you visualize, try this: compare `arr[ind[i, 0]:ind[i, 1]].mean()` in my version to `arr3[i]` in your implementation. The error happens because of weird indexing rules for `reduceat` and an offset I forgot about in `cumsum`.

Comment: @adirabargil. I've fixed the answer and added a third option.

Comment: Thank you very much, it’s evening here sonill check it out tommorow!

Comment: @adirabargil. No worries. I added some timings.

Comment: Wow thank you very much! This is alot of effort here, btw the size of arr as 100 and arr2 as 1000 this is more realistic to my situation.. ill get into it tomorrow, good night and thanks again!

Comment: @adirabargil. I've updated with your suggested numbers. Sorting and indexing is still 100x better than your original, 10x better than tiling.

Comment: are you sure mad 1 is not  faster because that the array is already sorted?

Comment: @adirabargil. I generate a new array for each function in the test. I'm sure it's not sorted. Also, sorting 10 elements is not going to have a noticeable impact

Comment: i looked into the mad_1 answer and it works perfectly... thank you very much! you are a total genius!

Comment: @adirabargil. Neat. I remember this! I like using numpy to dice numbers. It's a nice challenge sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Unless `arr2` is larger than `arr`, you will get very little performance improvement (if any) by vectorizing that loop.  All vectorized approaches will need to boardcast arr to arr2 giving an NxM structure with a size that will offset the benefits.

I measured various approaches:

```
import numpy as np

def original(arr,arr2):
    arr3 = np.zeros(arr2.size) # this is the array i want to store the result in
    for index, num in enumerate(list(arr2)):
        arr3[index] = np.mean(arr[np.abs(num - arr) < 0.2])
    return arr3
        
def vectorized1(arr,arr2):
    delta  = (np.abs(arr2[:,None]-arr)<0.2).astype(np.int)
    return np.sum(arr*delta,axis=1)/np.sum(delta,axis=1)

def vectorized2(arr,arr2):
    return np.fromiter((np.mean(arr[np.abs(num-arr)<0.2]) for num in arr2),np.float64)

def vectorized3(arr,arr2):
    return np.apply_along_axis(lambda num:np.mean(arr[np.abs(num-arr)<0.2]),1,arr2[:,None])

def vectorized4(arr,arr2):
    select  = np.array([np.nan,1])[(np.abs(arr2[:,None]-arr)<0.2).astype(np.int)]
    return np.nanmean(select*arr,axis=1)

def vectorized5(arr,arr2):
    arr_tile = np.tile(arr, (len(arr2), 1))
    arr_tile[np.abs(arr - arr2[:, None]) >= 0.2] = np.NaN
    return np.nanmean(arr_tile, axis=1)
```

*Note that vectorized2 and vectorized3 are not actually vectorizations of the calculations. They merely hide the loop that is being performed. Vectorized5 is Ananda's solution*

Results when arr is larger than arr2:

```
from timeit import timeit
count = 1

arr  = np.random.random(10000)
arr2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 2000)

t = timeit(lambda:original(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("original    time:",t)

t = timeit(lambda:vectorized1(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("vectorized1 time:",t)

t = timeit(lambda:vectorized2(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("vectorized2 time:",t)

t = timeit(lambda:vectorized3(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("vectorized3 time:",t)

t = timeit(lambda:vectorized4(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("vectorized4 time:",t)

t = timeit(lambda:vectorized5(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("vectorized5 time:",t)

original    time: 0.14478049999999998
vectorized1 time: 0.3868172580000001
vectorized2 time: 0.14587923599999986
vectorized3 time: 0.15062318699999988
vectorized4 time: 0.6438709420000002
vectorized5 time: 0.543624409
```

Results when arr2 is larger than arr:

```
arr  = np.random.random(100)
arr2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 200000)

print()
print(f"arr {arr.size}, arr2 {arr2.size}")
t = timeit(lambda:original(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("original    time:",t)

t = timeit(lambda:vectorized1(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("vectorized1 time:",t)

t = timeit(lambda:vectorized2(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("vectorized2 time:",t)

t = timeit(lambda:vectorized3(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("vectorized3 time:",t)

t = timeit(lambda:vectorized4(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("vectorized4 time:",t)

t = timeit(lambda:vectorized5(arr,arr2),number=count)
print("vectorized5 time:",t)

original    time: 1.7699030359999997
vectorized1 time: 0.38871579499999953
vectorized2 time: 1.782099327
vectorized3 time: 2.443001885
vectorized4 time: 0.5951444290000012
vectorized5 time: 0.4536258110000002
```

*note that this apparent improvement only holds true up to a point because, when memory is exceeded, the vectorized times will explode again even when arr2 is larger than arr.*

Comment: In fact on that measure, Arr2 is larger then arr... arr2 for about 5-10 times...

Comment: `vectorized2` and `vectorized3` are not vectorized at all. Increasing the number of dimensions is vectorizing, but is not the right approach, I think. Try the three sorting approaches I show.

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving this would be by setting all the numbers that *doesn't* fit your condition to `nan` and taking the mean of the rest.

```
import numpy as np 

arr = np.random.random((100))
arr2 = np.linspace(0,1,20)
arr3 = np.zeros(20) # this is the array i want to store the result in...

for index,num in enumerate(list(arr2)): 
    arr3[index] = np.mean(arr[np.abs(num - arr) < 0.2])
    
arr_tile = np.tile(arr, (len(arr2), 1))
arr_tile[np.abs(arr - arr2[:, None]) >= 0.2] = np.NaN
res = np.nanmean(arr_tile, axis=1)

np.allclose(res, arr3)
```

This gives `True`

Comment: Oh i see i was confused because you left the for loop.. let me try this when o get to my office

Comment: Yes sorry, I just left it so as to show that it does give the same solution as yours.

Comment: your solution i seems really smart and works well, but the issue is the memory size, it can overflow easily for bigger datasets... im still trying to figure out

Comment: thank you very much your solution eventually came in handy..!

Comment: This seems like the slowest approach: for large arrays, its a lot slower than the approach in the question.

Comment: after further investigation i see that numpy oerations that contains `nan` keyword are relativly slow...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, good to know about both the instances :-)