# Any faster way to index through this list with outfor and while loops? (python)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization

I'm trying to find a way to get rid of this while loop because its costly in time.
what I'm doing here is indexing  the list (data) to then find the highest value in between [x:x+9] and then adding that to another array (result) and then adding 1 to x to index through the entire list. Is this a stupid way of doing it? is there a faster more clever way?. Any help is much appreciated. I hope that I explained this well enough.

```
def calc(data):
    result = np.zeros(len(data)) # allocating space
    x = 0
    while x < len(a):
        highest_value = max(data[x:x+9])
        print(f'{data[x:x+9]} highest value = {highest_value}')
        result[x] = b
        print(result)
        x += 1
    return result

data = [7,6,5,4,3,4,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,5,4,2,3,1]

result = calc(data)
```

out:

```
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4] highest value = 7
[7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5] highest value = 6
[7. 6. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] highest value = 6
[7. 6. 6. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] highest value = 7
[7. 6. 6. 7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] highest value = 8
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] highest value = 9
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3] highest value = 9
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5] highest value = 9
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 4] highest value = 9
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 4, 2] highest value = 9
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3] highest value = 9
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1] highest value = 9
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[8, 9, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1] highest value = 9
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[9, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1] highest value = 9
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[3, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1] highest value = 5
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[5, 4, 2, 3, 1] highest value = 5
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[4, 2, 3, 1] highest value = 4
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 5. 4. 0. 0. 0.]
[2, 3, 1] highest value = 3
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 5. 4. 3. 0. 0.]
[3, 1] highest value = 3
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 5. 4. 3. 3. 0.]
[1] highest value = 1
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 5. 4. 3. 3. 1.]

______________________________________________________________
result: 

[7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 5. 4. 0. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 5. 4. 3. 0. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 5. 4. 3. 3. 0.]
[7. 6. 6. 7. 8. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 5. 5. 4. 3. 3. 1.]
```

Wall time: 7.01 ms

Comment: You might get more of a response on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, since this kind of question might be more appropriate for those sites. After appropriately modifying your question to fit those sites' rules, of course.

Comment: Considering this is already using Numpy, there might be a vectorization benefit.

Comment: @RandomDavis Possibly, but considering how little explanation there is I'm sure this wouldn't go over well on CR.

Comment: @Mast, what kind of vectorization you suggest?

Comment: And what exactly the output is?

Comment: The first thing I see is that you're running max on your whole window every time, but the window slides only 1 position each time.  Not sure the Python interpreter is smart enough to optimize that.  You should try it by hand and check.

Comment: @adirabargil I'm not sure, but Alain's answer looks like a good start.

Answer (score 5):

You can let numpy perform the calculations in parallel by providing it with a list of indexes for each sub range:

For example:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([7,6,5,4,3,4,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,5,4,2,3,1])

idx = np.arange(9)+np.arange(len(data))[:,None] # indexes of subRanges
idx = np.minimum(len(data)-1,idx)               # don't overflow indexes

rollingMax = np.max(data[idx],axis=1) # apply maximums on every subrange

print(rollingMax)
[7 6 6 7 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 5 4 3 3 1]
```

[EDIT] an even faster way is to loop through the value offsets rather than on the positions.  While this still involves a loop, it is much faster and sustains the speed improvement on larger data sets.

```
def rollingMax2(data,window=9):
    result = data.copy()
    for offset in range(1,window):
        result[:-1] = np.maximum(result[:-1],result[1:])
    return result

                         speed improvement
number of values     rollingMax   rollingMax2
           20             3x          3x
          200            15x         31x  
        2,000            26x         99x
       20,000            35x        167x
      200,000            21x        220x 
    2,000,000            11x         66x 
   20,000,000            11x         35x
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey thats a really nice answer.. can you look into my question too which has something similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495249/numpy-pandas-vectorize-custom-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment115797179_65495249

Comment: hi, in second tought does this faster in large datasets?

Comment: The larger the data set, the bigger the speed difference will be, up to a point where memory management becomes the bottleneck.  see edit with improved version and time measurements